# the identifier __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the replacement lists of variadic macros

Tags: c++, macros

I am attempting to create a macro to perform api calls. My current issue is the passing of parameters for the call. I get the following error message:

> the identifier __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the replacement lists of variadic macros

```
#define DO_CALL(api_name)(...) wow64hg::do_call(FNV(#api_name), __VA_ARGS__)

const auto status = DO_CALL(TerminateProcess)(process_handle, 0);
```

It technically may be possible to fix this by using operator loading, but I am confident there should be a way to keep it simple like this and get it to work.

Comment: For anyone looking, I had the same error because I just had a space between macro name and parentheses like #define DO_CALL (arg1, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Variadic macro syntax doesn't work like that; the `...` has to represent additional arguments of the macro.  A macro can't take multiple sets of arguments in separate sets of parentheses like an iterated function call.

I think you have to do the following:

```
#define DO_CALL(api_name, ...) wow64hg::do_call(FNV(#api_name), __VA_ARGS__)

const auto status = DO_CALL(TerminateProcess, process_handle, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually already knew that, and it works. However, we specifically want it in the format in my post(parenthesis separate for api name and args like DO_CALL(api_name)(...))

Comment: @MemeMachine I don't think you'll be able to achieve that with just a macro.  You could use a macro that expands to a lambda that wraps the actual call though.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0aeed02947059e4).

Comment: @MilesBudnek Hm, I see.